# Performance of list comprehensions in boolean indexing

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am currently trying to learn more about Pandas, and was looking at the [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) section in the documentation.

In the example given, it is noted that for a DataFrame

```
In[439]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'six'],
                             'b' : ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x'],
                             'c' : np.random.randn(7)})

In[440]: df2
Out[440]: 
       a  b         c
0    one  x -0.858441
1    one  y  0.643366
2    two  y -0.862198
3  three  x -0.408981
4    two  y  1.137740
5    one  x  0.829057
6    six  x -1.251656
```

using the `map` method of a Series like

```
In [441]: criterion = df2['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))

In [442]: df2[criterion]
Out[442]: 
       a  b         c
2    two  y  0.041290
3  three  x  0.361719
4    two  y -0.238075
```

is faster than the equivalent list comprehension

```
In [443]: df2[[x.startswith('t') for x in df2['a']]]
Out[443]: 
       a  b         c
2    two  y  0.041290
3  three  x  0.361719
4    two  y -0.238075
```

Now for this situation I would use `df2[df2.a.str.startswith('t')]` which wasn't mentioned in the docs, so I wanted to benchmark the approaches.

---

**Small Series benchmark**

```
%timeit df2[df2.a.str.startswith('t')]
1000 loops, best of 3: 880 µs per loop

%timeit df2[df2['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 783 µs per loop

%timeit df2[[x.startswith('t') for x in df2['a']]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 572 µs per loop
```

Surprisingly, the list comprehension approach seemed to be the fastest! So I tried making the DataFrame *much* larger and benchmarking again.

```
In[444]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'six']*1000000,
                             'b' : ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x']*1000000,
                             'c' : np.random.randn(7*1000000)})
```

**Big Series benchmark**

```
%timeit df2[df2.a.str.startswith('t')]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.89 s per loop

%timeit df2[df2['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.73 s per loop

%timeit df2[[x.startswith('t') for x in df2['a']]]
1 loop, best of 3: 3.95 s per loop
```

Still the list comprehension seems to be the fastest, and the difference is even more noticeable with a large Series.

---

### Question

Is the `map` method of a Series generally actually faster than a list comprehension for Boolean Indexing? Why does the list comprehension approach seem to actually be faster here and contradict the [documentation section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)?

There may very well be an error in my benchmarking approach or testing, and I am well aware that for more complex criterion (and even simple criterion) one of the first two approaches is *much* nicer to look at and implement, but my question here is just about performance.

*Note*: I am using Pandas version `0.18.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it's not about boolean indexing - it's about working with string series:

```
In [204]: %timeit df.a.str.startswith('t')
10 loops, best of 3: 75.7 ms per loop

In [205]: %timeit df['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))
10 loops, best of 3: 76.5 ms per loop

In [206]: %timeit [x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']]
10 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ms per loop

In [209]: %timeit [df.a.str[0] == 't']
10 loops, best of 3: 85.2 ms per loop
```

DF shape: 70.000 x 3

```
In [207]: df.shape
Out[207]: (70000, 3)
```

Often list comprehension is faster when working with `string` series.

PS i was using Pandas version 0.19.2 for this example

Comment: Yes of course, I guess the indexing occurs in the same way in each case anyways. I can look into this some more myself, but do you think this is probably just a slightly confusing example of something that is generally true? e.g. for other Series the documentation advice is usually correct?

Comment: I think you are using the best approach - test, profile, chose the best method for this particular task. One solution can can be better for this particular task and will be the slowest for another one... And yes, i saw it already quite a few times when list comprehension was faster for __string__ Series

Comment: @EricHansen, glad i could help :-)